# How to pipe through less to have a closer look on HOME, PATH USER?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, pipe

Type env at the command prompt to see your environment. Pipe the output through less to have a closer look. What is the value of your HOME, PATH, and USER variables?

I am thinking of using `grep` and `|` but I am not sure how to implement it as I keep getting No such File or directory.

Comment: Questions about how to use UNIX command-line tools are better suited for our sister site [unix.se]; Stack Overflow is only for specific, narrow questions about problems you encountered *while writing code*. Moreover, we frown on anything that looks like a homework dump -- you're welcome to ask about problems you encountered while trying to do homework, but the question needs to be about your problem, not about your homework.

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) on [meta] for guidance on how to ask about issues you encounter while doing homework in a way that's likely to get good answers and not make people grumpy.

Comment: @stevielol : You can search for a regexp in `less` too. Once you piped into `less`, type a slash (`/`) and you will be prompted to end a search pattern. Typing then `n` brings you to the next occurance of your search, and `N` to the previous one. See `man less`.

Answer (score 1):

```
env | egrep "HOME=|PATH=|USER="
```

Comment: Sorta. Not guaranteed to work right if any of those variables' values contain literal newlines. And `grep -E` is more portable than `egrep`, which is on the road to deprecation.

Comment: Also, anchoring at the front, as in `'^(HOME|PATH|USER)='` would avoid finding, say, `CLASSPATH=`.

Comment: There are other pathological cases as well. Consider `export myvar=$'\nUSER=fake_user\nhahahaha'`; a *correct* implementation wouldn't show the `USER=fake_user` line from the definition of `my_var`, but would only show the real USER variable's definition.

Comment: And, I conclude from the question, that the task was to use `less` for inspection/searching, so the whole question sounds more like _please, read the `less` man-page to me!_.